# Is probability of occurrence of a binary event simply the proportion of its occurrence?

Tags: probability, binary-data

I have a data frame with binary features `Weekday` and `Weekend` like this with occurrences of a specific event:

```
| ID | Weekday | Weekend
| ---| --------|--------
| 01 | 1       | 0
| 02 | 0       | 1
| 03 | 0       | 1
| 04 | 0       | 1
```

Now I'm expected to give "probabilities of event in weekdays and weekends respectively". Are these respective probabilities simply the proportions of events happening on weekdays/weekends? So probability of event happening on weekday is 1/4 (25%), while on weekend is 3/4 (75%)? So simple?

Comment: The estimates of those probabilities are the proportions that you mentioned. Also, the probabilities are equal to the limit of infinite trials

Answer (score 0):

It can be understood by the definition of Probability, but there are a lot of definitions for probability, which are Classical, Empirical, Axiomatic, Subjective...

Here we need to understand Classical and Empirical Probability

### Classical Probability

This is the Probability that is used most by non-statisticians and used in an introductory course: it simply implies the probability is a fraction whose numerator is the number  of events we are interested in and the denominator is the number of possible outcomes. For example, suppose we have a coin with two sides Head(H) and Tail(T) then the probability of obtaining Head

$$
P(H) = \frac{Number \ of \ Heads}{Total \ Number \ of \ Sides} = \frac{1}{2}
$$

It looks good and can be applied in your problem and we will get $\frac{1}{2}$, but it fails when the coin we are observing is biased.  suppose we have a coin that always turns into Head, there it fails and hence comes the **Empirical Probability**

### Empirical Probability

It is also known as the frequentist approach. We define
$$
f_n = \frac{M_n}{n}
$$

where $M_n$ number of favorable outcomes in n random experiments in an identical condition, and the probability is given by
$$
P(M) = lim_{n \to \infty}f_n
$$
So in your case, your approximation of Empirical Probability is correct, that is 1/4 and 3/4.